# How to force 403 or 404 on specific route

Tags: 8, routes, http-request

I have made a custom form to create nodes for a specific content type. Due to that, I want to throw a 403 or 404 on the admin page that creates new node. The route I mean is 'node/add/'.

I guess in my_module.routing.yml I have to add something like this:

```
<MY_CUSTOM_ROUTE>.add-node:
    path: '/node/add/<CONTENT_TYPE>'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'
```

But I'm not able to find the right controller. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a route where `_access` is set to FALSE, like this one from a test in core:

```
system_test.always_denied:
  path: '/system-test/always-denied'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Always denied'
    _controller: 'chop'
  requirements:
    _access: 'FALSE'
```

Although in this case an extra route shouldn't be necessary, because you can deny the permission to add a content type in UI.